# Ubuntu putty and serial port

Tags: usb, putty

Need putty to work on `/dev/ttyUSB0`

I know for a fact that the port (console on a switch) is 9600 8/n/1, so it should be simple.

ttyUSB0 shows up in dmesg.

So shouldn't I be able to select `/dev/ttyUSB0` in putty's serial configuration and it should work.

Works fine when I'm running putty with windows.
Doesn't work with Ubuntu/putty.  I get no response.

This is how I started it:

```
putty -serial -sercfg 9600,8,n,1,N
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: For my case, I had to hit an Enter to show "Router>" prompt (Cisco 6300, Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 17):

```
sudo putty /dev/ttyUSB0 -serial -sercfg 9600,8,n,1,N
```

worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I use minicom.
To install `minicom` use command

```
sudo apt-get install minicom
```

Start minicom setup with command

```
xxx@yyy ~ $ sudo minicom -s
```

You will get setup menu

[image]

go to `Serial port setup`

[image]

Change `Serial Device`

Change `Bps/Par/Bits`

After changes hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Save setings

[image]

Go to `Exit` to exit from setup in `minicom`

You minicom is ready

[image]

Comment: I had already tried minicom and kermit.  Both got no response - like putty.  But I'll give minicom another try using your steps/screenshots.

Comment: @Scott were you able to solve the problem, if yes can you please tell me how

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not provided the read and the write permission to group of /dev/ttyUSB0 file
ls -l /dev/USB0

Provide the permission:
**sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0**

Putty will work fine.

Comment: Is there a reason to modify the directory?

Answer (score 0):

sudo putty /dev/ttyUSB0 -serial -sercfg 115200,8,n,1,N -log  datas.log

we can get the serial port in that esp32 in 115200 in serial port in the log in the datas in the log in linux we can store the data directly from arduino serial monitor