# How to connect COM Port to the switch?

Tags: serial-port

I'm new to Ubuntu. I recently bought a PL2303 USB to Serial connector and had placed its driver PL2303.C to my Ubuntu 17.10.

I put the command 'lsusb', and it showed:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:28b4 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
**Bus 002 Device 005: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port**
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and when I checked the 'dmesg' command ==>  dmesg | grep tty 
it shows:

```
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[   19.113237] usb 2-3: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   25.449300] ttyS3: LSR safety check engaged!
[   25.449943] ttyS3: LSR safety check engaged!
```

But when I plug that serial to the console port of my switch (i used the original dongle, so dongle must be not an issue), it won't appear. I suspect the com port. but i already check it with the command ==> `setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0123456789]`, it shows :

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS3: No such device
/dev/ttyS4, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS5, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS6, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS7, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS8, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS9, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
```

how to set com port (/dev/ttyS0) in order to be able to connected to the switch? PLease advise

Comment: But your port is set to `ttyUSB0`.  Why are you trying to set on `ttyS*`?

Comment: how to revert it back ?

Comment: You don't.  The port was detected at `/dev/ttyUSB0` so that is what you use for the connection to the serial port.  `/dev/ttyS[0-9]` are for the built on serial ports to the motherboard which you are not using.

Comment: how to configure /dev/ttyUSB0 port so I can connect it to my switch's console port?

Comment: Use a program like `putty` to connect.   See the answers in https://askubuntu.com/questions/592386/ubuntu-putty-and-serial-port

Comment: I did, but didn't work.. My Ubuntu version is 17.10, I use Minicom instead, but still failed to connect

Comment: You really need to [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/996448/edit) your question and put in all the steps you have done and all the error messages you are getting.  BTW, I prefer putty for connections to serial.

Comment: I tried to install putty, but after install it, it didn't work. there's a crash title below:  " Putty crashed with SIGSEGV in XGetDefault", how to resolve this?

Comment: Oh yes, Ubuntu 17.10 now uses Wayland.  So X apps might have an issue.  Try logging into Ubuntu as XOrg https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10 then try the `putty` again.  Make sure you are also setting the correct speed for the serial connection.  It may be 115200 or 19200 or 9600.

Comment: You're very welcome!  I wrote it up as a quick answer to help others as well.  Glad it is working for you!  =)

Answer (score 1):

To use `putty` in Ubuntu 17.10, you need to launch Ubuntu in XOrg.  Follow the following answer to launch XOrg:  [How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Your USB Serial device is at `/dev/ttyUSB0`.  Make sure that you are using that for your `putty` connection.

```
sudo putty /dev/ttyUSB0 -serial -sercfg 9600,8,n,1,N
```

Make sure that you set the speed correctly for the console connection to the switch.  It might be `115200` or `19200` or `9600`.

Hope this helps!